# WordPress: кастомная страница и работа с БД

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется почти голый WordPress 3.9.
Требуется сделать страницу с набором input'ов и сохранить полученные данные в БД.
На другой странице нужно вывести эту таблицу. Внутри таблицы будут кнопки, например, поднять строку вверх и т.д.  
Подскажите, пожалуйста, простой способ это сделать, только общую схему, естественно, может быть, плагины полезные для этого есть? Как вообще решаются подобные вопросы на wordpress?
Спасибо.

Comment: [pods cms](http://pods.io/)

внутрь лучше даже не заглядывать

Comment: если нужно под конкретную страницу, то берем шаблон страницы, например, page-ваш_ид.php, и там же редактируем. Запросы можно через объект $wpdb выполнять, ничего сложного там. Лучше несколько строчек кода, чем установить плагин, и т.д.

Comment: @dmitmedv, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Все просто. Создаем в папке с темой Wordpress новый файл, например, `my-custom-page.php`. В самое начало этого файла добавляем следующий код:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Страница Инпутов
*/
?>
<?php echo 'Hello'; ?>
```

После этого создаем новую страницу в админке, справа в разделе шаблон выбираем **Шаблон страницы** -> **Страница Инпутов**. Теперь по адресу созданной нами страницы будет отображаться **Hello**. В этом файле мы можем писать интересующий наc код. Более подробно о шаблонах страниц в [официальной документации](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B).

Теперь немного про работу с бд. Можно использовать стандартный класс для работы с базой wpdb. Документация на русском относительно этого класса есть [тут](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb). Главное не забывать экранировать записываемы данные, либо использовать плейсхолдеры.

Пример инсерта в произвольную таблицу `my_custom_table`.

```
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO my_custom_table ( param1, param2, param3 ) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s )",array($param1,$param2,$param3)));
```